# Best solution for concurrent access to files within a webapp

Tags: java, guava

I am writing a webapp (SpringMVC +JSF) that allows users to upload their files and edit/share them with other people. On the service layer of this app I use guava to handle all file IO, but unfortunately from what I can see so far in the reference manual, guava does not address the problem of concurrent access to files.

I am aware that the FileChannel class provided by Java has a lock method that addresses this issue to some extent, but it doesn't fit well with guava IO framework. Before I get rid of guava and rewrite my code with FileChannel and InputStream, I want to know if there is any other way to do this without entirely switching to another IO package.

(A large hash table mapping file names to locks doesn't look like a good solution to me. When user base is large there is too much to store in the memory.)

Comment: Could you just `synchronize` on the `File` objects rather than having locks?

Comment: @bmorris591 there will be lots of files so the objects will be destroyed immediately at the end of any IO function call. Maybe creating a database table with filename, Set<User> readers, Set<User> writers is the ultimate solution for applications like this, but I would only do that if there is really no other simple solution.

Comment: @bmorris591 In addition to that, it is not a good idea to block readers when others are reading. Marking file objects as "synchronized" would cause this undesirable behavior.

Comment: You could get the monitor _before_ opening a `Reader`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a database. File-system is great for storing the actual file content -- but as for storing  & managing Users, File Details, Sharing, and Edit & Version History etc, a database is absolutely required.

To avoid information loss from a failed upload, uploads & edits (for example) need to go to a new file -- not overwrite the existing one, and perhaps trash it.

Edits & sharing will also presumable be to an entity (a row in a 'DOCUMENT' table, perhaps) which may have successive versions (the actual file on disk).

Therefore, for at least two reasons, the 'filesystem file' is distinct from the entity you will need to track & your users wish to work with.

If your supposed user base *does* ever get large, they will probably expect a real application. With a reliable database, recording user access, document versions, sharing & the location & lock state of the underlying files on disk, is easy & reliable.

Without such a database, it's not possible to do reliably.

Comment: But _do_ use the filesystem for storing the actual file content -- FS is much more efficient for such purpose. Don't use a BLOB.

Comment: Thanks. This is true. It would be nice if there is some specialized database to store file content and handle synchronization issues implicitly, or an open source library in this area. There is definitely a demand for that.

Comment: Synchronization is not too bad -- just have a DOCUMENT.STORED_FILE column, or a DOC_VERSION.STORED_FILE column. Once the upload/ new version succeeds, just update or store the record with the (internal path) of the new file data. Database queries will only ever see results with complete & valid files.. what could be simpler?